# Best practice for REST API url format when it's stateful with session?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, session

I am writing a full stack app. I am using front end templating, not server side.

I originally wrote my routes to be api endpoints with restfull standards. So, for instance....on the front end if a user wanted to view their profile I would have the api call out:

```
router.route('/users/:userId')
  .get(isLoggedIn, api.getUserById)
```

These api endpoints are not public in the manner to be consumed by other apps, they are just for the front end web app to consume.

I am using session tracking to do this, because the user will always stay logged in once they are logged in. I realize that I do not need the user ID number in the api call, because I can just get it from the session object. With that being said, how should I construct the `/users/:userId` route? I no longer need the `:userId` because I can get it from the session object. But if I did something like `/profile` it looks crummy and not to restful standards(even though I am doing session tracking so it is statefull).

What would be the best way to make the route for best practices?  `/profile`  or `/users/:userId` even though I don't need `:userId`?

Comment: i will use /users/me

Comment: **Alternative** If you are following *restful* pattern then why are you making it stateful, best practice is to use tokens for user *authentication* rather than storing in *session*. One of the ways is to use [JWT](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), you can store userid as a payload and later retrieve it while authenticating.